# Adding to static ArrayList just overwriting the first element

Tags: java, arraylist, static

I have a static arrayList used elsewhere in my code called jobsList.  I would like to add elements to it using a static method.  For some reason it is overwriting the jobList so that every time I add an element, the 1st element is the element I just added and nothing else.  As in, no other elements are ever added.  Relevant code below:

```
public static ArrayList<Job> jobList = null;

public JobSchedule() {
    jobList = new ArrayList<Job>(10);

}

public static Job addJob(int time) {
    System.out.println("Adding job " + time);
    Job j = new Job(time);

    jobList.add(j);
    System.out.println("Current joblist size: " + jobList.size());
    System.out.println("First element: " + jobList.get(0).weight);
    return j;
}
```

The output from the printlines looks like this:

```
Adding job 8
Current joblist size: 1
First element: 8
Adding job 5
Current joblist size: 1
First element: 5
```

Ideally each time I add it should increment the size and put the job at the correct index, so I'm not sure why the arraylist is being overwritten.

Comment: answer is because its static. remove every static and it works

Comment: `static ArrayList<Job> jobList`....    `public JobSchedule() { jobList = new ArrayList<Job>(10); }`, something looks not right here.

Comment: Do you mean the method or the arrayList?  I need the arrayList to remain static and when i remove static from the method declaration I still get the same problem.

Comment: How are you calling this method?

Comment: In between consecutive addJob call are you calling new JobScheduler();?

Comment: Kevin Esche - I want to be able to run a sort on an arraylist in the superclass from the subclass but the only way i know to do that is by making the arraylist in the superclass static.  But then I was having issues during testing because my setup/teardown was not destroying the old arraylist so creating a new schedule and adding to it was just adding to the previous arraylist.  I'm not sure how to go about fixing this.

Comment: `static` are class independent so basically you are not initializing your `arraylist`

Answer (score 3):

I think you're calling the constructor every time,

```
JobSchedule(){
    jobList = new ArrayList<Job>(10);
}
```

This creates a new ArrayList every time you call it.

No need for the constructor. Do something like this:

```
public static ArrayList<Job> jobList = null;

public static Job addJob(int time) {

    if (jobList == null) {
        jobList = new ArrayList<Job>(10);
    }
    System.out.println("Adding job " + time);
    Job j = new Job(time);

    jobList.add(j);
    System.out.println("Current joblist size: " + jobList.size());
    System.out.println("First element: " + jobList.get(0).weight);
    return j;
}
```

Comment: I'm not calling the constructor from within the body of the addJob.  I also need the constructor to actually create the (graph-like) job schedule so I can do other things from the schedule class, like sort.

Comment: No need to do anything in the constructor. Apart from anything else, the code here is not thread safe. Assign the list when it is declared.

Comment: if you are calling the constructor you are initializing list every time and if you are not calling constructor *you are putting values in `null` list* which is more worse

Answer (score 1):

In your current code, when you invoke your constructor `new JobSchedule()`, **a brand new ArrayList object will be created and assigning to the same reference**.

Infact, I would suggest you to mark your `jobList` reference variable with `private`, `static` and `final` as shown below:

```
private static final ArrayList<Job> jobList = new ArrayList<Job>(10);
public JobSchedule() {
}
public static Job addJob(int time) {
  System.out.println("Adding job " + time);
  Job j = new Job(time);

  jobList.add(j);
  System.out.println("Current joblist size: " + jobList.size());
  System.out.println("First element: " + jobList.get(0).weight);
  return j;
}
```

`private` - can be accessed within the same class

`static` - maintained a single copy for the whole class

`final` - the reference can't be reassigned (also can't be inherited) with a new `arraylist`

It is not recommended to expose your whole `jobList (arraylist)` as a `public` variable, rather try to get a specific `Job` using some `getJob(T t)` method (so is the reason I have marked it as `private`).

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that before calling `addJob(5)`, you're calling the constructor `JobSchedule()`, which is overriding the static list.

To address this, avoid initializing static variables in instance methods

```
public static ArrayList<Job> jobList = new ArrayList<Job>(10);

public JobSchedule() {
}
```

And the code should work as expected. Alternatively, make both the `jobList` field and the `addJob` method non-static. You'd also have to NOT call the constructor each time before calling `addJob`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.  I ended up rewritting my code so that it takes an empty constructor, and making a subclass just a normal nested class, passing in an instance of the super class in the nestedclass object and then being able to call sort() on that.

```
public JobSchedule() {}

public Job addJob(int time) {
    Job j = new Job(time, this);
    jobList.add(j);
    return j;
}

Nested class...{
public JobSchedule schedule = null;

    private Job(int time, JobSchedule schedule)
    {
        this.schedule = schedule;
        this.weight = time;
    }

    public int getStartTime() {
        schedule.kahnSort();
        .
        .
        .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you add element every time before your new a JobSchedule object. Do not instantize the static ArrayList in the constructor